# How to get smart contract attributes by some block in mainnet?

Tags: brownie, mainnet

I want to track some smart contract's attributes in the neighbouring blocks in mainnet. I know hash of the contract and hash of the 'starting' block. I use brownie. How can I get attributes of the smart contract by the block?

I request the block with `tx = web3.eth.getBlock(tx_id)`, but do not know what to do next

Answer (score 0):

Just make a call like you normally would and add `block_identifier` parameter at the end of it. Example:

```
stEth = Contract.from_explorer("0xae7ab96520de3a18e5e111b5eaab095312d7fe84")
stEth.balanceOf("0x123...", block_identifier=16882875)
```

The above code will return what the contract would return at the block number: 16882875